# Foreach generating multiple forms in codeigniter - values coming wrong

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I did a foreach to render sales coupons, so the user can choose one and cancel that coupom. He put his password and the attendant can cancel that sale.

Problem: on submit, always the last form values are submited. Why? I guess probably it's id or submit button name problem, but don't know certainly. tested put id on form, different names on submit, etc; nothing works.
So, if I put the user password on the first generated form, the password input comes empty. But if I put the password on the last generated form the input comes ok! Besides, the values in hidden inputs are always from the last form. I'm using one form and one submit button for each coupom. All of them have the same atributes and input (probably the problem) but I can't figure it out.
Any ideas? Two days working on it and nothing until now.

Foreach code:

```
<?php
$queryCancel = $this->posweb->get_last_transactions($id)->result();
    foreach ($queryCancel AS $cupom) {
?>
<?php echo form_open('posweb/operacao'); ?>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdidUser" value="<?php echo $query->idUser ?>"/>

    <label>User Password</label>
    <input name="pswUser" type="password" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btnSalvar btn btn-block btn-danger btn-danger-border">
        Cancel this coupom
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="operation_type"
           value="cancelSale">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: there is only one form element in this code?

Comment: @BrianRamsey no. Php is generating 10 forms like this, one below other. (10 last sales/coupom)

Comment: Your code paste must be incomplete then... are you using CI validation library?

Comment: @BrianRamsey Yes, I'm using, but not validating password because it only comes with POST if I fill the last (10/10) form. The pasted code it's the php in the view. The code generated is almost equal to this, with the difference that there are 10 forms 1 below the other. And the <?php echo form_open('posweb/operacao'); ?> turn in to <form action="http://site.com.br/module/posweb/operacao" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> - the rest of code is equal

Answer (score 0):

No concrete answers yet to help, so I changed the logic.
Instead of using 10 forms, removed `<form>` tag and inside div becomes an `<a>` tag.
That `<a>` tag link to a bootstrap modal and I pass the vars from link to modal via data-href's.
Put all data from php that I need in hidden inputs and submit then with user input password. 
It works.

View:

```
<?php
$queryCancel = $this->posweb->get_last_transactions($id)->result();
    foreach ($queryCancel AS $cupom) {
?>
<div>
    <a data-href="<?php echo $query->userId ?>" data-valid="<?php echo $query->valid_date ?>" data-idloja="<?php echo $idLoja ?>" data-estab="<?php echo $query->cnpj_loja ?>" data-valor="<?php echo $cupom->valor ?>" data-dtcompra="<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($cupom->created_at)) ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancel-sale" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-danger-border" title="Cancelar Venda"><span class="label label-default label-size"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span></a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

-- modal --

```
<div class="modal fade modal-3d-slit" id="cancel-sale" aria-hidden="true"
 aria-labelledby="exampleModalTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> Atenção</h4>
        </div>
        <?php
        echo form_open('posweb/operacao');
        ?>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert dark alert-alt alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <strong>
                    <span>Ask the customer to enter your password</span>
                </strong>
            </div>

            <label>Customer Password</label>
            <input name="pswUser" type="password" class="form-control" />
            <br>
            <!--button type="submit" class="btnSalvar btn btn-block btn-danger btn-danger-border">
                Cancel this Coupom
            </button-->

            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue" name="hdUser" />
            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue2" name="hdvalidDate" />
            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue3" name="hdidLoja" />
            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue4" name="hdEstab" />
            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue5" name="hdValor" />
            <input type="hidden" class="inputValue6" name="hdDtCompra" />

            <input type="hidden" name="operation_type" value="cancelSale" />

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default margin-0" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Confirmar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript - pass the php vars you want from clicked `<a>` to modal:

```
$('#cancel-sale').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    $('.inputValue').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href'));

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('valid', $(e.relatedTarget).data('valid'));
    $('.inputValue2').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('valid'));

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('idloja', $(e.relatedTarget).data('idloja'));
    $('.inputValue3').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('idloja'));

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('estab', $(e.relatedTarget).data('estab'));
    $('.inputValue4').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('estab'));

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('valor', $(e.relatedTarget).data('valor'));
    $('.inputValue5').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('valor'));

    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('dtcompra', $(e.relatedTarget).data('dtcompra'));
    $('.inputValue6').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('dtcompra'));

});
```

Hope help someone with same problem.
I would still like to know why when there is more than one form with the same elements on a page, the values submitted are always the ones of the last form.
If you know why, please let me know.

Comment: I've got a sneaking suspicion that only the last form was being submitted, but as your initial question only had a small piece of your code, no one could help you...

Comment: @BrianRamsey you're right. Only the last form is submitted. But that is what I said in inicial question. I thought the code I put in was enough to understand the problem, because the generated HTML is 10 forms equal to this (outside of PHP). I thought a lot of unrelated code could disrupt the person willing to help.I thought it was a silly mistake on my part, like repeating the name of the elements in different forms. That it was something simple and easy that I had forgotten or did not know. However, thanks for your time and help!